# Can't find assembly - System.Reactive.Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reactive-extensions-js

I have installed visual studio 2010 express and then Reactive Extensions 2.0. When I start my app in debug mode, part of code where reactive extensions is used following exception is thrown:

```
    The assembly with display name 'System.Reactive.Debugger' failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure was: 

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 

'System.Reactive.Debugger, Version=2.0.20823.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies
```

The problem is that nowhere I can find this dll - System.Reactive.Debugger.